# Bash scripting, loop through files in folder fails

Tags: bash

I'm looping through certain files (all files starting with MOVIE) in a folder with this bash script code:

```
for i in MY-FOLDER/MOVIE*
do
```

which works fine when there are files in the folder. But when there aren't any, it somehow goes on with one file which it thinks is named MY-FOLDER/MOVIE*.

How can I avoid it to enter the things after

```
do
```

if there aren't any files in the folder?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
for i in $(find MY-FOLDER/MOVIE -type f); do
  echo $i
done
```

The `find` utility is one of the Swiss Army knives of linux.  It starts at the directory you give it and finds all files in all subdirectories, according to the options you give it.

`-type f` will find only regular files (not directories).

As I wrote it, the command will find files in subdirectories as well; you can prevent that by adding `-maxdepth 1`

---

*Edit, 8 years later (thanks for the comment, [@tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87189/tadman)!)*

You can avoid the loop altogether with

```
find . -type f -exec echo "{}" \;
```

This tells `find` to `echo` the name of each file by substituting its name for `{}`. The escaped semicolon is necessary to terminate the command that's passed to `-exec`.

Comment: find is swiss army knife, true. but used it such a way with for loop is prone to fail upon files with spaces.

Comment: Additionally, this will split on the `echo $i` since you left I unquoted. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7039579/3076724) for examples of better syntax.

Comment: This won't work if your filenames have spaces in them.

Answer (score 14):

With the `nullglob` option.

```
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ for i in zzz* ; do echo "$i" ; done
$
```

Comment: your code works for me even without the `nullglob` option, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @DenisGolomazov: You have files that match. Try using a glob that matches no files.

Answer (score 3):

```
for file in MY-FOLDER/MOVIE*
do
  # Skip if not a file
  test -f "$file" || continue
  # Now you know it's a file.
  ...
done
```