# Looping through all files in a directory

Tags: bash, shell, loops

I want to write a shell script that will loop through all the files in a directory and echo "put ${filename}". Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What  have you tried?  What part of the `for` statement and the `*` operator confuse you?  Can you be more specific about what you know and what you don't know about the shell?

Comment: Just came across this -- a warning to anyone using this as a reference -- the answers do not handle filenames with spaces properly...  refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039130/iterate-over-list-of-files-with-spaces for a better solution!!!

Answer (score 68):

For files and directories, not recursive

```
for filename in *; do echo "put ${filename}"; done
```

For files only (excludes folders), not recursive

```
for file in *; do 
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then 
        echo "$file" 
    fi 
done
```

For a recursive solution, see Bennet Yee's answer.

Comment: If the current directory happens to be empty, this outputs "put *" rather than correctly outputting nothing.  Can it be fixed?

Comment: @ThisClark - Indeed it does.  But I'm not sure that an answer not doing *exactly* what you want is a good reason to downvote.

Comment: @ThisClark - True.  But being generous to myself (!), one could argue that from a *nix perspective, a folder **is** is a file.  (Possibly that's what I was thinking when I wrote the answer 7 years ago, but who knows...)

Comment: What does nix even stand for? Disregarding the distinction of files from folders is not helpful.

Comment: @ThisClark *nix meaning unix, linux, etc.

Comment: This does not list any hidden files (i.e. those starting with ".") in bash on macOS 10.13. Is that normal? How do I get all files, including the hidden ones?

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann try running 'shopt -s dotglob' right before.

Comment: What if one wants to pass the name of the directory as a variable (I posted a more precise question there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76021261/passing-a-string-to-a-loop-to-iterate-in-all-subdirectories-and-files)

Answer (score 21):

## Recursively (including files in subdirectories)

```sh
find YOUR_DIR -type f -exec echo "put {}" \;
```

## Non-recursively (only files in that directory)

```sh
find YOUR_DIR -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec echo "put {}" \;
```

---

Use `*` instead of `YOUR_DIR` to search the current directory

Comment: I get the error `find 'dir': No such file or directory` when trying this.

Comment: Silly me, by dir you meant replace with the directory you want. Still, slightly confusing!

Comment: Recursively for files in the current directory, replace `dir` with `*`.

Comment: What does this part do? "put {}" Especially meaning of the curly braces {}

Comment: use '.' for all files in the current directory instead of 'dir'.  note that find will also go through the "hidden" files/directories the names of which start with a dot.

Comment: the '{}' is replaced with the path to the filesystem object identified by the conditions specified earlier.

Comment: wouldn't a pipe with `$1` be easier than the ` -exec echo .. {} `? Also, I just noticed that find isn't GNU compliant with it's options syntax.  Is it not a core util? Sorry for digging up this grandad of a Q / A, but it is a popular page, and I felt that I had useful info to add (the first part, not the second. ).

Answer (score 8):

For all folders and files in the current directory

```
for file in *; do
    echo "put $file"
done
```

Or, if you want to include subdirectories and files only:

```
find . -type f -exec echo put {} \;
```

If you want to include the folders themselves, take out the `-type f` part.

Comment: This does not list files starting with a "." in bash v3 (macOS). Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have any files, then instead of printing * we can do this.

```
format=*.txt
for i in $format;
do
 if [[ "$i" == "$format" ]]
 then
    echo "No Files"
 else
    echo "file name $i"
 fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

One more alternative using `ls` and `sed`:

```
$ ls -1 <dir> | sed -e 's/^/put /'
```

and using `ls` and `xargs`:

```
$ ls -1 <dir> | xargs -n1 -i%f echo 'put %f'
```

Comment: +1, but -1 is not needed and you can do sed -e 's/^/put /'

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks, I've updated my response. Somehow, I misunderstood and made the braces and the dollar sign part of the solution. Also, I'ved another solution with `xargs` and `echo`, but the `sed` one is still more concise.

Answer (score 0):

this will work also recursively if you have any sub directories and files inside them:

```
find . -type f|awk -F"/" '{print "put ",$NF}'
```