# Multiple elements instead of one in bash script for loop

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, ubuntu-16.04

I have been following the answers given in these questions

> [Shellscript Looping Through All Files in a Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512462/shellscript-looping-through-all-files-in-a-folder)
>
> [How to iterate over files in a directory with Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796200/how-to-iterate-over-files-in-a-directory-with-bash)

to write a bash script which goes over files inside a folder and processes them. So, here is the code I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

YEAR="2002/"
INFOLDER="/local/data/datasets/Convergence/"

for f in "$INFOLDER$YEAR*.mdb";
do
    echo $f
    absname=$INFOLDER$YEAR$(basename $f)

    # ... the rest of the script ...

done
```

I am receiving this error: **basename: extra operand**.

I added `echo $f` and I realized that `f` contains *all the filenames* separated by space. But I expected to get one at a time. What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into problems with quoting. In the shell, double-quotes prevent word splitting and wildcard expansion; generally, you don't want these things to happen to variable's values, so you should double-quote variable references. But when you have something that *should* be word-split or wildcard-expanded, it *cannot* be double-quoted. In your `for` statement, you have the entire file pattern in double-quotes:

```
for f in "$INFOLDER$YEAR*.mdb";
```

...which prevents word-splitting and wildcard expansion on the variables' values (good) but also prevents it on the `*` which you *need* expanded (that's the point of the loop). So you need to quote selectively, with the variables inside quotes and the wildcard outside them:

```
for f in "$INFOLDER$YEAR"*.mdb;
```

And then inside the loop, you should double-quote the references to `$f` in case any filenames contain whitespace or wildcards (which are completely legal in filenames):

```
echo "$f"
absname="$INFOLDER$YEAR$(basename "$f")"
```

(Note: the double-quotes around the assignment to `absname` aren't actually needed -- the right side of an assignment is one of the few places in the shell where it's safe to skip them -- but IMO it's easier and safer to just double-quote all variable references and `$( )` expressions than to try to keep track of where it's safe and where it's not.)

Answer (score 2):

Just quote your shell variables if they are *supposed* to contain strings with spaces in between.

```
basename "$f"
```

Not doing so will lead to splitting of the string into separate characters ([see WordSplitting in `bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html)), thereby messing up the `basename` command which expects one string argument rather than multiple.

Also it would be a wise to include the `*` outside the double-quotes as shell globbing wouldn't work inside them (single or double-quote).

```
#!/bin/bash

# good practice to lower-case variable names to distinguish them from
# shell environment variables

year="2002/"
in_folder="/local/data/datasets/Convergence/"

for file in "${in_folder}${year}"*.mdb; do
    # break the loop gracefully if no files are found
    [ -e "$file" ] || continue 
    echo "$file"
    # Worth noting here, the $file returns the name of the file
    # with absolute path just as below. You don't need to 
    # construct in manually
    absname=${in_folder}${year}$(basename "$file")
done
```

Comment: glob would expand to nothing only when `shopt -s nullglob` is set and there are no matching files. So, I think Inian's `[ -e "$file" ]` is valid.

Answer (score 0):

just remove "" from this line
for f in "$INFOLDER$YEAR*.mdb";

so it looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash

YEAR="2002/"
INFOLDER="/local/data/datasets/Convergence/"

for f in $INFOLDER$YEAR*.mdb;
do
    echo $f
    absname=$INFOLDER$YEAR$(basename $f)

    # ... the rest of the script ...

done
```

Comment: This is a hypercorrection; you correctly unquote the `*`, but *incorrectly* unquote the parameter expansions.