# Accessing multi-word directory names in a shell script

Tags: sh

I'm trying to get a list of directory names in `i`.  For example,

```
for i in `ls`
do
```

However, `ls` accesses a directory which contains multi-word directories, people's names, `John Doe`.  If I just use `` `ls` ``, then a two word name becomes two values for `i`.  If I use `` "`ls`" ``, I get one long string of all the names in `i`.  I tried using `"ls -1"` to force one line per entry but that didn't work either.  Is there a solution?

Comment: [This article](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) explains why parsing `ls` is a problem; use `for i in ./*` instead (and then refer to `i` with double quotes, `"$i"`). There has to be a duplicate somewhere...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20796200/3266847 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/8512462/3266847 are similar, but not *exact* duplicates

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looping through all files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512462/looping-through-all-files-in-a-directory)