# How do you write a script that creates a list of every file in a directory then uses a for loop to print each file name one at a time?

Tags: bash

For example I want to list every file in var/log, how do I go about doing this? I've tried searching for answers but couldn't find anything on this.

Comment: See: [Looping through all files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8512462/3776858)

Comment: `for file in /var/log/*; do ...; done`