# Shell script: Passing a string as variable to a loop and iterate in all subdirectories and files

Tags: string, loops, shell, for-loop, path

I want to loop through all the subdirectories and files of a directory. If I passed the directory directly through the loop, the loop iterates successully through all the files and subdirectories and prints them:

```
for f in /path/to/directory/*; do
  echo $f
done
```

If I pass it as a variable (string)

```
dir="/path/to/directory/*"

for f in $dir; do
  echo $f
done
```

It simply prints `/path/to/directory/*` ( does not loop through all the files and directories)

Comment: globs don't take effect inside quotes. `dir="/path/to/directory"; for f in "$dir"/*`

Answer (score 0):

list file:

```
find /path/to/directory/ -type f
```

list path:

```
find /path/to/directory/ -type d
```