# Unix CLI script to rename folders using their pre-existing names

Tags: regex, bash, unix, rename

I have a directory with folder structure as follows:

```
-- DATA -- ABD 1231345 -- 01-08-12 // date in mm-dd-yy format
                       -- 03-09-12
                       -- 06-11-12

        -- DEF 4859480 -- 02-10-12
                       -- 05-10-12
                       -- 07-10-12
```

I would like to batch rename this `DATA` folder as follows

```
-- DATA -- ABD 1231345 -- 2012_01_08 // date in yyyy_mm_dd format with underscore
                       -- 2012_03_09
                       -- 2012_06_11

        -- DEF 4859480 -- 2012_02_10
                       -- 2012_05_10
                       -- 2012_07_10
```

Do you have a suggestion on how to accomplish using command line on Mac OSX / unix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `for` loop and `awk`, parsing each file-name into your specified format and then `mv` to rename the original to the new name:

```
for dir in DATA/*; do \
    pushd "$dir"; # change directory \
    for file in *; do \
        path=`echo $file | awk -F- '{print "20"$3"_"$1"_"$2}'`; \
        mv $file $path; # "rename" the file \
    done; \
    popd; # restore original directory \
done;
```

This can be executed in folder above `DATA`. If you want to execute it directly in `DATA`, update the first loop to read `for dir in *; do` instead of `DATA/*`. It tells `awk` to use the `-` as the delimiter (instead of whitespace), and then reconstructs a string from "mm-dd-yy" to "20yy_mm_dd".

Using [`pushd`](http://ss64.com/bash/pushd.html) and [`popd`](http://ss64.com/bash/popd.html) will enable the script to change the current directory to each subdirectory inside `DATA` (`pushd`) and then, after moving all necessary files will change back to the original (`popd`). Doing this will save you a lot of parsing-effort trying to save directory paths / etc.

Comment: I just noticed that if I'm in the parent folder `/DATA` I cannot run your solution - it only works if I'm in the next level `ABD 1231345` -- how can I get your code to work without `cd`'ing into each first-child folder?

Comment: @torr Updated to traverse the directories; I used `pushd` and `popd` to do so - both of which are mentioned in chepner & Mat's answers (the latter linking to another question with these commands) opposed to string-manipulations to save a headache =]

Comment: a problem I'm having is that the folders have a space between `ABD` and `123143` -- for example `ABD 12314435`. That is causing the script to fail as it seems to get the folder name only before the space -- so I get multiple messages like `-bash: pushd: ./ABD: No such file or directory`

Comment: @torr Sorry, I should've expected that; try adding double-quotes around the `pushd "$dir";` (I've updated the answer to show too).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [string manipulations](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) and [arrays](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html) to do that with bash only.

Something like:

```
for f in * ; do
  parts=(${f//-/ })
  mv "$f" "20${parts[2]}_${parts[1]}_${parts[0]}"
done
```

Search this site for various options to recurse into directories e.g.:
[Shell script to traverse directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610955/shell-script-to-traverse-directories)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `date` command to convert the file name:

```
$ date -j -f %m-%d-%y 01-08-12 +%Y_%m_%d
2012_01_08
```

Getting to the files is a little tricker. We'll just switch directories to avoid dealing with long file paths.

```
for d in DATA; do
    pushd "$d"
    for f in *; do
        new_f=$(date -j -f %m-%d-%y $f +%Y_%m_%d)
        mv "$f" "$new_f"
    done
    popd
done
```

Answer (score 0):

[This site](http://snipplr.com/view/2736/) gives a good snippet

```
for i in *.avi; do j=`echo $i | sed 's/(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/20\3_\1_\2/g'`; mv "$i" "$j"; done
```