# Batch converting file encoding

Tags: shell, xargs

I have bunch of files are encoded with GB2312, now I want to convert them into UTF-8, so I apply the code below:

```
find . | xargs iconv -f GB2312 -t UTF-8
```

It successfully convert them but the output is printed in console.

Here I want them to be saved in their original files, how do I make it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use a loop instead of `xargs`.  I wouldn't recommend overwriting files in a one-shot command-line call.  How about moving them aside first:

```
for file in `find .`; do
    mv "$file" "$file.old" && iconv -f GB2312 -t UTF-8 < "$file.old" > "$file"
done
```

Just take care with this.  If your file names contain spaces, this loop might not work correctly.

Comment: You code works like a charm, thanks ! Just for curious, is there any one line command to make it ?

Comment: You can put it all on one line if you place a semi-colon after the loop body *ie* `for ...; do mv .... > "$file"; done`

Comment: By the way, if you have spaces in your filenames, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039130/bash-iterate-over-list-of-files-with-spaces

Comment: There should be a $ before... ```for file in `find .`; do
    mv "$file" "$file.old" && iconv -f GB2312 -t UTF-8 < "$file.old" > "$file"
done``` This killed one of my code repo sadly.