# Execute "ffmpeg" command in a loop

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I have three `.wav` files in my folder and I want to convert them into `.mp3` with ffmpeg.

I wrote this bash script, but when I execute it, only the first one is converted to mp3.

What should I do to make script keep going through my files?

This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -name '*.wav' | while read f; do
    ffmpeg -i "$f" -ab 320k -ac 2 "${f%.*}.mp3"
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No reason for [find](/questions/tagged/find), just use [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) wildcard globbing

```
#!/bin/bash
for name in *.wav; do
  ffmpeg -i "$name" -ab 320k -ac 2 "${name%.*}.mp3" 
done
```

Comment: That will not handle subdirectories.

Comment: Downvoted. This is a workaround that explains `bash` features, not a solution to the actual problem with `ffmpeg`. See Shammell Lee's answer.

Comment: There are possible throws if no pause in loop(as to me) so this one is working too avoiding throws:                                                       **`#!/bin/bash
FILES="/path/*.mp4"
for f in $FILES
do
  echo "------Processing $f VIDEO..."
  sudo ffmpeg -i "$f" -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 192K -f mp3 "$f.mp3"
  echo "======Processed to $f.mp3"
  read -t 3 -p "Pause 3 sec ..."
done`**                                                                                                           . put it as __sh__ script chmod +x this_script.sh  and  __sudo ./this_script.sh__

Answer (score 77):

Use the `-nostdin` flag to disable interactive mode,

```
ffmpeg -nostdin -i "$f" -ab 320k -ac 2 "${f%.*}.mp3"
```

or have `ffmpeg` read its input from the controlling terminal instead of stdin.

```
ffmpeg -i "$f" -ab 320k -ac 2 "${f%.*}.mp3" </dev/tty
```

See the `-stdin`/`-nostdin` flags in the [ffmpeg documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html)

Answer (score 19):

If you do need `find` (for looking in subdirectories or performing more advanced filtering), try this:

```
find ./ -name "*.wav" -exec sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "$1" -ab 320k -ac 2 "$(basename "$1" wav).mp3"' _ {} \;
```

Piping the output of `find` to the `while` loop has two drawbacks:

1. It fails in the (probably rare) situation where a matched filename contains a newline character.
2. `ffmpeg`, for some reason unknown to me, will read from standard input, which interferes with the `read` command. This is easy to fix, by simply redirecting standard input from `/dev/null`, i.e.  `find ... | while read f; do ffmpeg ... < /dev/null; done`.

In any case, don't store commands in variable names and evaluate them using `eval`. It's dangerous and a bad habit to get into. Use a shell function if you really need to factor out the actual command line.