# Bash Script - iterating over output of find

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have a bash script in which I need to iterate over each line of the ouput of the find command, but it appears that I am iterating over each Word (space delimited) from the find command. My script looks like this so far:

```
folders=`find -maxdepth 1 -type d`

for $i in $folders
do
    echo $i
done
```

I would expect this to give output like:

```
./dir1 and foo
./dir2 and bar
./dir3 and baz
```

But I am insted getting output like this:

```
./dir1
and
foo
./dir2
and
bar
./dir3
and
baz
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: See also answer #1 in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you aren't using any of the more advanced features of `find`, you can use a simple pattern to iterate over the subdirectories:

```sh
for i in ./*/; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: Most answers talk about using while. But, I was trying to find a solution that involved only a for loop and your solution works great. My scenario was to fetch filename from a different folder. So, added a small change to this : `(cd $folder; for i in ./*/; do echo "$i"; done)`. Created a subshell, for running this on my shell without having to change folder paths

Answer (score 27):

```
folders=`foo`
```

is always wrong, because it assumes that your directories won't contain spaces, newlines (yes, they're valid!), glob characters, etc. One robust approach (which requires the GNU extension `-print0`) follows:

```
while IFS='' read -r -d '' filename; do
  : # something with "$filename"
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0)
```

Another safe and robust approach is to have `find` itself directly invoke your desired command:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec printf '%s\n' '{}' +
```

See the [UsingFind](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) wiki page for a complete treatment of the subject.

Comment: Note that the `find ... -exec` form only works for normal commands -- if you want to use shell builtins, shell functions, compound commands, etc you need to use either the `while ... done` approach or the `for` loop chepner suggested.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Generally true. However, the UsingFind wiki page (linked in my answer) describes using `-exec bash -c '...' _ {} +`, which allows shell builtins and the like to be used.

Comment: Warning! Some commands, including ffmpeg, will read from stdin, and confuse the "read" command used in the loop. Symptoms are beginnings of the filename being cut off (=> invalid names). You need to disable this behaviour in the command that reads from stdin, two solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21634699

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d | while read -r i
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: Unsafe. Doesn't correctly handle filenames containing backslash sequences, newlines, runs of multiple whitespace characters, etc.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy fixed and checked both `\`, and whitespaces

Comment: ...better -- with the `-r` you've handled backslash sequences, but you're still expanding globs, compressing runs of whitespace into a single character, and stripping trailing whitespace.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy how to check it? I've checked two whitespace, it handles that

Comment: Checked *how*? The problem you still have here is two spaces directly in a row, not two spaces anywhere in the filename.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy do you mean this '  '? or sometihng else?

Comment: ...so, to be clear, the problem is the unquoted expansion passed to the echo. For instance, if `i=$'foo\tbar'`, `echo $i` will print `foo bar`, with a space rather than a tab between the `foo` and the `bar`, because string-splitting breaks it into two separate arguments.

Comment: ...but even if you fix that, your answer is _still_ wrong for directory names containing newlines. Yes, they're valid -- try `mkdir -p $'foo\n/etc'` and see what you get.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `mkdir -p $'foo\n/etc'` this code won't work both in your, and chepner's code. As for the  $'foo\tbar': result good in all of the three codes.

Comment: Incorrect -- what I gave *definitely* works in both my code and chepner's. If you think it doesn't, explain exactly why and how you reach that conclusion.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I've checked

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47125/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and--)

Comment: Better still. The only bugs this still has -- which both chepner's answer and mine don't -- are unsafe embedded newline handling and stripping of trailing whitespace.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you second variant too has =)

Comment: The second variant passes filenames to `printf` with the newline intact -- it's just hard to tell the difference between the printf emitted by newline as part of the filename and the newline emitted by printf according to the format string, so they're still there, so it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Charles Duffy's answer (kudos!), I made a bash function `qfind` (quoted find) which outputs all the output of `find` but quoted. I am adding it to my `.bashrc`

```bash
qfind() {
    while IFS='' read -r -d $'\0' findOutput; do
        /usr/bin/echo -n "${findOutput@Q} "
    done < <(/usr/bin/find "$@" -print0)
}
```

The quoted strings are separated with whitespace. `${findOutput@Q}` expands to the quoted value of `${findOutput}` like `"$(quote "$findOutput")"`. When `-n` is removed from `echo`, it will also use newline characters for separation.

It can be used like this

```bash
eval "folders=($(qfind . -maxdepth 1 -type d))"
for i in "${folders[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

`eval` is required to evaluate any quoted substrings.

With the predefined function, there won't be any additional commands in the loop body that read characters away from stdin during the loop.