# How to run md5sum parallely on some 10 files named test1...test10 in the directory

Tags: bash, shell

I'm able to run serially but unable to run it parallely. My code is as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
  for i in `find ~/Mainstore-1/ -maxdepth 1 -type f`
  do
    md5sum $i
  done
  sleep 1
done
```

Comment: [Don't iterate the results of `find` like that!](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21663090/418066) What do you think will happen if there's a file with whitespace in its name? And quote your variables!

Comment: What's the purpose of the `while` loop? Are you expecting the files to be changed over time, or new ones to be added?

Comment: i'm expecting that new files will get added to that directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
find ~/Mainstore-1/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | while read -d '' -r file ; do
    # launch md5sum in background using `&`
    md5sum "$file" &
done

# Wait for workers to finish
wait
```

Comment: Watch out for files with newlines in their names, though.

Comment: @Biffen Yeah for sure, good old new lines! :) I was wondering if it can be achieved using find's exec option..

Comment: `find ~/Mainstore-1/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -I filename -exec bash -c "md5sum {} &" \;`

Comment: @anishsane Yeah, or even simpler `-exec md5sum {} +` Note the `+`. However, this would not process the checksums in parallel. (At least I doubt that md5sum is implemented this way, however I'm not sure)

Comment: `IFS=''`, `-print0` and `-d ''` is another way to go. But in this case `-exec` has a bit more beauty to it.