# Bash script does not sort by file type after IF

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I need some help, guys. I have a bash code

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Iveskite kataloga, kurio analize norite atlikti"
read katalogas
failai=$(find -x $katalogas)
for failas in $failai
do
  if [[ -d "$failas" ]]
  then 
    echo $failas " yra direktorija "
  else
    if [[ -x "$failas" ]]
    then
      echo $failas " yra vykdomasis failas "
    else
      if [[ -f "$failas" ]]
      then
        echo $failas " yra paprastasis failas "
      fi
    fi
  fi
done
```

I want to make, that the final result would be sorted by file type. I do this: `failai=$(find -x $katalogas)` but It seems not working.

Comment: What platform are you on?  I have never seen the `-x` flag to find before so I'm not sure what it's supposed to do

Comment: [Don't iterate the results of `find` like that!](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21663090/418066) What do you think will happen if there's a file with whitespace in its name?

Comment: @Eric Renouf, from manage for BSD find "−x  Prevent **find** from descending into directories that have a device number different than that of the file from which the descent began."

Comment: Also, you might be interested in the fact that bash supports `elif` so you can avoid `else if` nesting like you're doing

Comment: It's linux, if I understand your question correct (I test it on Yosemite terminal)

Comment: @semkius, run your code through [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) and double-quote the variables it suggests to be double-quoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution that means you keep your script mostly unchanged:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Iveskite kataloga, kurio analize norite atlikti"
read katalogas
failai=$(find -x $katalogas)
typeD=fileslist1
typeX=filelist2
typeF=filelist3
> $typeD
> $typeX
> $typeF
for failas in $failai
do
  if [[ -d "$failas" ]]
  then 
    echo $failas " yra direktorija " >> $typeD
  else
    if [[ -x "$failas" ]]
    then
      echo $failas " yra vykdomasis failas " >> $typeX
    else
      if [[ -f "$failas" ]]
      then
        echo $failas " yra paprastasis failas " >> $typeF
      fi
    fi
  fi
done
cat $typeD $typeX $typeF
```

Or, to avoid writing to files and using "sort", you would need to add a sort key to your output accordingly, i.e. change the "D:" "X:" and "F:" to fix the order as required:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Iveskite kataloga, kurio analize norite atlikti"
read katalogas
failai=$(find -x $katalogas)

for failas in $failai
do
  if [[ -d "$failas" ]]
  then 
    echo "A: $failas  yra direktorija "
  else
    if [[ -x "$failas" ]]
    then
      echo "X: $failas yra vykdomasis failas "
    else
      if [[ -f "$failas" ]]
      then
        echo "F: $failas yra paprastasis failas "
      fi
    fi
  fi
done | sort
```

You can option add a " | cut -d':' -f2- " after the "sort" to remove the sort key.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably simplest to just run `find` three times. (This also avoids any issues that might come up while trying to store all the found file names in a single list, such as with file names containing spaces.) Unless `katalogas` contains a *lot* of files, this is unlikely to be a bottleneck for your script.

```
echo "Iveskite kataloga, kurio analize norite atlikti"
read katalogas
# First, get the directories
find -x "$katalogas" -type d
# Next, get anything with a permission bit set
# Ignore directories you already found
find -x "$katalogas" -not -type d -perm -111
# Find any regular files not matched by the above
find -x "$katalogas" -not -type d -not -perm -111 -type f
```

Comment: `find: -perm: x: illegal mode string`

Comment: Oh, I missed the last line of the docs that say a symbolic mode may not begin with a dash. Try `-perm -111` instead.

Comment: Hm. `-perm` isn't working the way I expect. I seem to be getting a lot of files that don't have any execute bits set.

Comment: use the -executable flag maybe? I think this solution is probably the best if you can get it working. The file cache will mean it doesn't have to actually do much actual disk reading after the first find.