# Execute bash in multiple similar directory

Tags: php, bash, cron

I'm currently using a bash script with a lot of "same" lines.

```
cd /home/admin/web/mysite1.com/public_html/admin/; /usr/bin/php cron.php &
cd /home/admin/web/mysite2.com/public_html/admin/; /usr/bin/php cron.php & 
cd /home/admin/web/mysite3.com/public_html/admin/; /usr/bin/php cron.php & 
cd /home/admin/web/mysite4.com/public_html/admin/; /usr/bin/php cron.php &
```

I would like to know if it's possible to execute a command like this

`/usr/bin/find /home/admin/web/*/public_html/admin/  -name 'cron.php' php cron.php`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a simple for loop

```
for i in /home/admin/web/*/public_html/admin/cron.php; do
    /usr/bin/php "$i" &
done
```

See also this question for good answers: [Bash Script - iterating over output of find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21663090/bash-script-iterating-over-output-of-find)