# Invalid stream specifier: metadata

Tags: ffmpeg

I have this command:

```
ffmpeg -i video.format -movflags use_metadata_tags -map metadata 0 -vcodec libx265 -acodec copy output.mp4
```

I get this error:

```
[avi @ 0x559845f9c480] Invalid stream specifier: metadata.
    Last message repeated 3 times
Stream map 'metadata' matches no streams.
To ignore this, add a trailing '?' to the map.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want it to do when the input contains no audio and/or no metadata? Your command has a typo: `-map metadata 0` should be `-map_metadata 0` (although this is default so you can omit it).

Comment: Thanks! Well, currently, when i try to run this on a file with no audio/metadata, i get an error and the command stops. I'd like to keep running, and just ignore the audio/metadata parts when those are absent

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44249993/10248678). Ffmpeg consumes stdin, that's why the loop terminates too early.

Comment: @oguzismail the loop is absolutely irrelevant to my problem here. I want to use a generic command to treat files with and without audio and metdata

Comment: Your tagging says `bash`, your title says `batch`. These are very different things (a "batch file" is a Windows cmd.exe script, not a bash script).

Comment: oops! you're correct. I meant batch as in, doing a lot of things

Comment: If you want this reopened, you will probably have to spell out in more detail what your actual question is. If you want to try `a` and then fall back to `b` if it fails, the syntax for that is `a || b`. The error message also seems to suggest a possible remedy.

Comment: BTW, note that `find ... | while read filename` is a bit buggy in and of itself. If you want it to work with all possible filenames, `find ... -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' filename` is more reliable.

Comment: @Orsu edit your question to leave the loop part out and add the ffmpeg tag then. Good luck!

Comment: i think i'm going to delete it... apparently ffmpeg already does the thing i wanted, and the problem was using -map metadata instead of -map_metadata even tough it didn't complained before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command has an invalid option: `-map metadata 0` should be `-map_metadata 0` (although this is default so you can omit `-map_metadata 0`).

Once fixed the command should work regardless of the presence of audio and/or metadata.

Comment: surprinsingly, it always worked without complaining, but that's correct. THat's the fix. Thank you