# unix: looping through results of find command

Tags: bash, shell, loops, unix, find

I have a find command that outputs as I would like (it looks for files with strelka in the name and ends with .vcf):

> > find . -name *strelka* | grep '.vcf$'

But I want to then iterate over each and perform additional stuff.

To simply experiment, I'm just having it do a line count on each file (but ultimately I would want to do more in the end, this is just me playing around), but it already doesn't seem to work.

I have :

> > for i in `find . -name \*strelka\* | grep '.vcf$'`; do wc -l $i; done

Anyone know what is wrong with this?

Comment: Please don't improve the commands in the question or both the question and answers get pointless.

Comment: Several solutions fail if filenames contain spaces or other special characters. To address that issue, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039130/iterate-over-a-list-of-files-with-spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use find . -name '*strelka*.vcf', thereby avoiding the grep and letting you use find ... -exec
2. Either pipe into xargs, or use -exec:

   ```
   find . -name '*strelka*.vcf' | xargs wc -l  

   find . -name '*strelka*.vcf' -exec wc -l '{}' \;
   ```

Prefer the latter, for various reasons.

Your approach (with a $(...) around your find) is OK, except:

- You'll have grief if there are spaces in filenames. (You'd have grief with xargs too - there's a way round that involving \0, but it's a bit arcane.)
- You'll exceed the command line length limit if there are too many matching files.

Comment: The `xargs` version will call `wc` many fewer times, possibly once (depending on how many files there are). The `-exec` version as written will call `wc` once per file. In the former case, you'll get possibly useful (or possibly undesired) totals from `wc`. You could modify the `-exec` case to do the same by changing the `\;` to `+`.

Comment: for the first option using `find` and `xargs` I would suggest to use: `find . -print0 -name '*strelka*.vcf' | xargs -0 wc -l`. Its is to ensure you dont end up having problems with wierd filename containing `\n` or other preblematic chars.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using a recent (4.0 or greater) version of `bash`, you don't need to use `find` for this; a file pattern is sufficient, along with the `globstar` option.

```sh
shopt -s globstar
for i in **/*strelka*.vcf; do
    wc -l $i
done
```

For a small number of files, you can probably just use

```
wc -l **/*strelka*.vcf
```

For a large number of files,

```
find -name '*strelka*.vcf' -execdir wc -l '{}' +
```

is most efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your command as follows:

```
for i in $(find . -name \*strelka\* | grep '.vcf$'); do wc -l $i; done
```

or

```
find . -name \*strelka\* | grep '.vcf$' | while read i; do wc -l $i; done
```

or

```
find . -name \*strelka\* | grep '.vcf$' | xargs wc -l
```

You can also improve you find command to look for `\*strelka\*.vcf` to avoid the grep.

Also pay attention that files might contain spaces or even newlines. They would probably break your command. Therefore the best way is probably using:

```
find . -name '*strelka*.vcf' -exec wc -l '{}' \;
```