# How to use wildcard in the middle on the string? bash

Tags: bash, filenames

I am writing a bash script

My files are like:
 `file="${nodeID}_00000_19700101010${ts}_udp_filtered.pcap"`. Is it possible to instead of `00000` use any 5digit number? I thought about using

> `file="${nodeID}_`*`_19700101010${ts}_udp_filtered.pcap"`

sometimes I have 00001, sometimes 00004, etc.

Comment: "Is it possible to instead of 00000 use any 5digit number?" In what context?

Comment: after some simulation I have many files like: 1_00000_19700101010009_udp_filtered.pcap
3_00000_19700101010009_udp_filtered.pcap
7_00002_19700101010013_udp_filtered.pcap

and I would like to make file="${nodeID}_00000_19700101010${ts}_udp_filtered.pcap" working for any 5digid that comes instead of 00000

Like with the extensions of the files. When I put `*.pcap` i can work with any file that has .pcap extension. In my case I would like to work with all the files that instead of 00000 they have 00001 or 00009, whatever

Comment: "make `file=...` working" ... what's "working"? What are you doing with `file`? What should happen if more than one file matches?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like

```
 echo "${nodeID}"_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_19700101010"${ts}"_udp_filtered.pcap
```

Note, `*` and `[something]` won't expand in quotes, so only the variables are quoted above.

Answer (score 0):

```
for match in ${nodeID}_*_19700101010${ts}_udp_filtered.pcap
do
  #echo $match
  #do something with $match
  #file=$match
done
```

This will find all the matches in the directory and allow you to do something with them. The asterisk will match *any* string, not just 5 digits. You can be more specific in the regex, but if you know the format of the filenames, you can determine whether the * is safe or needs to be more specific.

Comment: `for match in $(ls ${nodeID}_*_19700101010${ts}_udp_filtered.pcap)` --- Never ever use `$(ls ...)`, it's broken and doesn't do what you want it to do. You want `for match in ${nodeID}_*_19700101010${ts}_udp_filtered.pcap`. No `ls`, no `$()`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it's broken and doesn't do what you want it to do"? It works for me and it does what I want it to do. Are there some special edge cases you are referring to?

Comment: Try filenames with spaces in them. Also try a directory matching your pattern with lots of files in it.

Comment: @NanoDano More specifically see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039130/bash-iterate-over-list-of-files-with-spaces)