# Whats wrong with the following command?

Tags: bash

I am new to bash. Can someone please point me to the error in the code.

```
for x in `ls`;do `if(echo $x|grep "-2"); then rm $x; fi`; done;
```

I am basically trying to remove all the files ending with "-2.jpg"

Comment: This question could have been more instructive had you included the issues you are seeing.

Comment: How about `rm *-2.jpg`?

Comment: @glennjackman I was just playing with bash and it was more of an informative answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use command substitution (backquotes) inside your `for` block. Command substitution is only used for getting the output to be used for assigning to a variable or for evaluating as another command.

```
`if(echo $x|grep "-2"); then echo 'yo'; fi`
```

You also need to add a space between `if` and the expression that follows it:

```
if (echo $x|grep "-2"); ...
```

Command substitution is also not necessary:

```
if echo $x | grep "-2"
```

You can also use `-q` to prevent messages being shown from `grep`:

```
if echo $x | grep -q "-2"
```

You also need to use `-e` to preven `-2` from being interpretted as a wrong option to grep:

```
if echo $x | grep -q -e "-2"
```

Some of your variables should also be placed inside double quotes to prevent word splitting:

```
if echo "$x" | grep -q -e "-2"
```

Prefer `$()` over backticks when doing command substitution as well:

```
for x in $(ls);do ...
```

Finally the better form:

```
for x in $(ls); do if echo "$x" | grep -q -e "-2"; then echo 'yo'; fi; done
```

#### Additional recommendations:

Better not get values through word splitting as it's also subject to pathname expansion and unexpected changes may occur. Use `while read` loop and process substitution instead. With `ls`, use `-1` as well to show entries line by line:

```
while IFS= read -r x; do if echo "$x" | grep -q -e "-2"; then echo 'yo'; fi; done < <(ls -1)
```

When doing command substitution or process substitution, if the last command is a call to an external binary, add `exec` to prevent unnecessary fork:

```
$(exec ls -1)
<(exec ls -1)
```

You can also just use comparisons over using `grep`:

```
if [[ $x == *-2* ]]; then
```

Comment: Good recommendations, but really should just have `for x in *` rather than all the `ls` stuff.

Comment: @BroSlow I was actually wanting to discuss that and `globstar` too but perhaps I had explained too much already that I just forgot it :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the backquotes for the `do` part, otherwise it means that you want to execute the filename. Also consider this alternative:

```
for x in `find -name "*-2.jpg"`; do echo $x; echo "yo"; done
```

Comment: `find != ls`, and this is going to suffer from largely the same issues as `for whatever in $(ls)` does, and more since you'll likely get more files which will take forever to buffer. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7039579/3076724) for a better syntax to iterate `find` results (though no loop is really needed here)

Comment: @BroSlow Thanks for the link and of course you're right, but the OP said he needs to find files with that suffix, so `find` should be ok. For the syntax, it was to be closer to the OP one, to be more effective, and for the issues, the OP code doesn't work because of one issue that my solution does not present. Every command could have its issues, but we should address only the one stated in the question.

Comment: Addressing `only the one stated in the question` is ok, but it's not going to be particularly helpful when the user runs into other issues from using an error-prone syntax, or when other users see the answer and assume it's an example of good syntax. And `find` can obviously get the same results as the user is asking about in the question, but not without arguments, e.g. something like `find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \! -name '.*'` would essentially mimick `ls`.