# How to replace a string in multiple files?

Tags: python, linux, perl, sed

I want to replace a string which occurs in several files. For a single file I am able to do using unix command :

```
sed 's/error("/printf( "ERROR : /g' all_reset_test.c > new_reset/all_reset_test.c
```

which replaces all `'error("'` with `'printf( "ERROR : '` in this file.

But I have over 100 files for which I need to do this. I am looking for how to run this command for all files at once in either a perl or a python script.

Comment: where are the files? in the same folder?

Comment: Would it not be easier to make a change to your error() function to add the "ERROR" prefix instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sed's option `-i`

Quoting from sed's manpage:

```
-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]

      edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
```

If you omit the SUFFIX sed will not create a backup before modifying the file.

In your case this

```
sed -i 's/error("/printf( "ERROR : /g' *.c
```

should do the job (without pyhton, perl, or a bash loop).

Answer (score 1):

For example, if your files have the extension .txt, you can use this:

```
%> perl -pi -e 's/error("/printf( "ERROR : /' *.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple bash for loop to apply this logic to all of your files:

```
for f in $(ls *.c); do 
   sed 's/error("/printf( "ERROR : /g' ${f} > new_reset/${f}
done
```

The `$(ls *.c)` portion should be replaced by whatever `ls` command will select the files that you want to apply the sed command to.

Comment: This may have produced the expected output for some specific set of input files but it's wrong in general in a couple of ways that will cause surprising failures given different file names and directory contents. Never use `for` on the output of `ls` and always quote your variables unless you fully understand the consequences and have a specific goal in mind. The correct syntax for this approach would be `for f in *.c; do sed '...' "$f" > "new_reset/$f"; done` but see @branch14's answer for the better approach.

Comment: -1 for adding a superfluous and buggy command substituion instead of sticking to plain globbing.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your `sed` command in a `for` cycle:

```
for file in $(cat file_list)
do
    sed 's/error("/printf( "ERROR : /g' $file > new_reset/$file
done
```

Of course, the list of files to edit can be obtained in multiple ways:

```
for file in $(ls *.c)  # if the files are in the same folder
do
    sed 's/error("/printf( "ERROR : /g' $file > new_reset/$file
done
```

Or

```
for file in $(find -type f -name '*.c')
do
    sed 's/error("/printf( "ERROR : /g' $file > new_reset/$file
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over files in the shell e.g. this finds all the `.txt` files in the subdirectories below the current directory. Each file is available in `$f`

```
for f in $(find . -name \*.txt); do
   # run my sed script for $f
done
```

There are numerous options for iterating over a set of files using bash. See [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-loop-over-file/) for some options. If you filenames have spaces, you will have to be careful, and [this SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039130/bash-iterate-over-list-of-files-with-spaces) details some options.