# bash script create file in dir containing (multiple) file types

Tags: bash, find

I want to create a file (containing the dir name) in any sub dir of e.g music that has at least one but maybe more .mp3 file. I want one file created no matter if there is one or more .mp3 in that dir and the dir can have whitespace.. I tried something like this:    `for i in $(find . -name "*.mp3" -printf "%h\n"|sort -u); do echo "$i" ; done`

This breaks the path into 2 lines where the whitespace was so:

```
./directory one
```

outputs as:

```
./directory
one
```

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7039579/3076724) should help you. Not particularly sure why you need the `sort`.

Comment: You should tell us exactly what you want to do. Don't be in the following situation: _You want to solve X. You think that to solve X, you need Y. You don't know how to achieve Y, so you come to SO to ask about Y._ The problem with this approach is that while we'll be good at answering about Y, maybe, you'll need something completely unrelated to Y... Why are you, in the first place, using `sort`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construct `$( ... )` in your

```
for x in $(find ... | ... | ... ) ; do ... ; done
```

executes whatever is in `$( ... )` and  passes the newline separated output that you would see in the terminal if you had executed the `...` command from the shell prompt to the `for` construct as a long list of names separated by  blanks, as in

```
% ls -d1 b*
bianco nodi.pdf
bin
b.txt
% echo $(ls -d1 b*)
bianco nodi.pdf bin b.txt
%
```

now, the `for` cycle assign to `i` the first item in the list, in my example `bianco` and of course it's not what you want...

This situation is dealt with this idiom, in which the shell reads ONE WHOLE LINE at a time

```
% ls -d1 b* | while read i ; do echo "$i" ; ... ; done
```

in your case

```
find . -name "*.mp3" -printf "%h\n" | sort -u | while read i ; do
       echo "$i"
done
```

hth, ciao

---

### *Edit*

My anser above catches the most common case of blanks ***inside*** the filename, but it still fails if one has blanks at the beginning or the end of the filename and it fails also if there are newlines embedded in the filename.

Hence, I'm modifying my answer quite a bit, according to the advice from [BroSlow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3076724/broslow) (see comments below).

```
find . -name "*.mp3" -printf "%h\0" | \
sort -uz | while IFS= read -r -d '' i ; do
     ...
done
```

#### Key points

1. `find`'s `printf` now separates filenames with a `NUL`.
2. `sort`, by the `-z` option, splits elements to be sorted on `NUL`s rather than on newlines.
3. `IFS=` stops completely the shell habit of splitting on generic whitespace.
4. `read`'s option `-d` (this is a *bashism*) means that the input is split on a particular character (by default, a newline).
   Here I have `-d ''` that bash sees as specifying `NUL`, where  BroSlow had `$'\0'` that bash expands, by the rules of parameter expansion, to `''` but may be clearer as one can see an explicit reference to the `NUL` character.

I like to close with "Thank you, BroSlow".

Comment: This takes care of most error cases, but will still filenames with eols, preceding and trailing whitespace, and other special characters. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039130/bash-iterate-over-list-of-files-with-spaces/7039579#7039579) for how to properly loop over `find` results, and `-z` option of `sort`.

Comment: @BroSlow As the OP mentions `.mp3` files... given the names that I've actually seen applied to `.mp3` files... I think that your correction is very welcome! Please, in your opinion, have I to edit my answer to take into account your comment, or is the link you gave sufficient to the purpose.?

Comment: Everyone should really avoid whitespace and special characters in any filenames, but it's generally a poor assumption to assume people will actually do it. I think just switching it to `find . -name "*.mp3" -printf "%h\0" | sort -uz | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' i` will catch every edge case.