# Bash while stops at first iteration

Tags: bash, shell, awk, while-loop

I am currently a bash script that shall check some data. What I got so far is:

## !/bin/bash

```
#!/bin/bash

find "./" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    folder=${file##*/}
    echo "Checking ${folder} for sanity..."
    ./makeconfig ${folder} | while read -r line; do
        title=`echo $line | awk -F' ' '{print $2}'`
        echo $title
    done
done
```

Now what it currently does is: Search every directory in `./` and extract the folders name (thus: removing the `./` from the result of `find`). Then give it to a self-written tool, which will output some lines like this:

```
-t 1 -a 2
-t 3 -a 5
-t 7 -a 7
-t 9 -a 8
```

of which I gather the value behind `-t` via awk. This also works so far, the problem is, the outer while loop stops after the first iteration, thus checking only one folder. My guess is that the two `read` commands of the inner and outer loop are colliding somehow. The tool `makeconfig` definitiveley returns `0` (no error) always. I tried to debug it using `sh -x script.sh` but it does not show me anything I can deal with.

Can someone point me in the right direction here what is going wrong? If you need ANY further informations, I can give them to you. Ive written a quick mimicking program if you want to test the bash script here (also a script now, just echoing some stuff), just make it executable via `chmod +x`:

```
echo "-t 3 -a 4"
echo "-t 6 -a 1"
echo "-t 9 -a 5"
```

Just put this with the script in a folder and create some subfolders, that should do it to make it work (as much as it does).

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: This is NOT a duplicate as  mentioned. The problem here are more the nested read commands than the `print0` (maybe that has also something to do with it, but not entirely).

Comment: Use `-print`, not `-print0`.

Comment: That `print0` and `IFS` look suspicious to me.  Try just `print`.

Comment: This works for some cases, but somehow it still stops in the middle (but doing a little bit more iterations)

Comment: If your files have spaces in them, you need to deploy some tricks.  [Examples.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039130/bash-iterate-over-list-of-files-with-spaces)

Comment: @Barmar: This is not a duplicate.

Comment: That question shows how to read the output of `find -print0`. Isn't that what you need to know?

Comment: No, the problem is the nested read command. The outer read command somehow conflicts with the inner one, resulting in only one loop iteration. Even the solution suggestes in the other thread (ive read it before posting!) wont do any good to the script.

Answer (score 0):

`IFS=` isn't setting the field separator to the null string (`\0`), but unsetting it entirely, so the entire output of the `find` command is being read at once. If you run it without the `-print0` argument to `find` it'll be easier to work with in bash. Two other alternatives:

1. use `xargs` to run a shell script on each item found with that being the sole argument
2. use `-exec` to run the shell script on each item.