# How to list files and match first line in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, sh

I would like to check for (only) python files for those which do not have the `#!/usr/bin/env python` in the first line.  So, I write a bash script that does the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

#list all of python files

for file in `find . -name "*.py"`
do
        if [ `head -1 $file` != "#!/usr/bin/env python"] then;
                 echo "no match in file $file"
        else then;
                 echo "match!"
        fi
done
```

However, for some reason I cannot get the `if` statement correct!  I've looked at many questions, but I cannot find one that succinctly describes the issue.  Here is the error message:

```
./run_test.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
./run_test.sh: line 9: `    else then;'
```

where am I going awry?  Thank you.

Comment: correct syntax is : `if [[ \`head -1 $file\` != "#!/usr/bin/env python" ]]; then`. also delete the then; after else

Comment: Change `] then;` to `]; then`.

Comment: Why is the double brackets (`[[` and `]]`) necessary?  It doesn't work without them - I just checked.

Comment: Either you need to surround command in double quotes or use [[. If output of head -1 $file is more than one word or null, then it will break [ syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like

```
find . -type f -name '*.py' -exec \
  awk 'NR==1 && /#!\/usr\/bin\/env python/ \
  { print "Match in file " FILENAME; exit } \
  { print "No match in file " FILENAME; exit }' \
{} \;
```

If you are going to loop over it, [don't use a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7039579/3076724)

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -type f -name '*.py' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
  if [[ $(head -n1 "$file") == "#!/usr/bin/env python" ]]; then
      echo "Match in file [$file]"
  else
      echo "No match in file [$file]"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Things to notice:

1. The [] after your if statement needs correct spacing
2. The ';' (if you enter a new line is not necessary) goes after the **if** and not after the **then**
3. You added an extra **then** after the else.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   #list all of python files

   for file in `find . -name "*.py"` 
   do
        if [ `head -1 $file` != "#!/usr/bin/env python" ]; 
        then
            echo "no match in file $file"
        else 
            echo "match!"
        fi
   done
   ```

Answer (score -1):

can you use `-exec` option by any chance? I find it easier.

```
find . -name "*.py" -exec head -1 {} | grep -H '#!/usr/bin/env python' \;
```

You can control the output using `grep` options.

---

### edit

Thanks to @chepner - To avoid the pipe being swallowed too early:

```
-exec sh -c "head -1 {} | grep -H '#!/usr/bin/env python'" \;
```

Comment: I like this since this most definitely seems like a one-off kind of task.

Comment: Yeah, I like this....what does the `-H`  option do?  I read the man page, but it doesn't make sense to me:  ` -H      Always print filename headers with output lines.`

Comment: oh, it should print the name of the file, before the matching text. I think `-lHZ` may actually be best for you, giving just zero-terminated filenames.

Comment: You can't have a pipeline in the argument to `-exec`.

Comment: Oops I didn't test it, my bad. Anyone suggest the fix? Can I enclose in  `$()` or quotes for example?

Comment: `-exec sh -c "head -1 {} | grep -H '#!/usr/bin/env python'" \;`

Comment: @SanjayManohar `-exec sh -c '...'` creates a subshell. Fine in morre complicated cases, but just piping as in op's original edit is better/faster here.