# grep cannot read filename after find folders with spaces

Tags: macos, bash, grep, find

Hi after I find the files and enclose their name with double quotes with the following command:

`FILES=$(find . -type f -not -path "./.git/*" -exec echo -n '"{}" ' \; | tr '\n' ' ')`

I do a for loop to grep a certain word inside each file that matches find:

`for f in $FILES; do grep -Eq '(GNU)' $f; done`

but grep complains about each entry that it cannot find file or directory:

`grep: "./test/test.c": No such file or directory`

see picture:

[image]

whereas `echo $FILES` produces:

```
"./.DS_Store" "./.gitignore" "./add_license.sh" "./ads.add_lcs.log" "./lcs_gplv2" "./lcs_mit" "./LICENSE" "./new test/test.js" "./README.md" "./sxs.add_lcs.log" "./test/test.c" "./test/test.h" "./test/test.js" "./test/test.m" "./test/test.py" "./test/test.pyc"
```

**EDIT**
found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7039208/1073786). works perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your array contains filenames surrounded by literal `"` quotes.

But worse, `find`'s `-exec cmd {} \;` executes `cmd` separately for each file which can be inefficient. As mentioned by @TomFenech in the comments, you can use `-exec cmd {} +` to search as many files within a single `cmd` invocation as possible.

A better approach for recursive search is usually to let `find` output filenames to search, and pipe its results to `xargs` in order to grep inside as many filenames together as possible. Use `-print0` and `-0` respectively to correctly support filenames with spaces and other separators, by splitting results by a null character instead - this way you don't need quotes, reducing possibility of bugs.

Something like this:

```
find . -type f -not -path './.git/*' -print0 | xargs -0 egrep '(GNU)'
```

However in your question you had `grep -q` in a loop, so I suspect you may be looking for an error status (found/not found) for each file? If so, you could use `-l` instead of `-q` to make `grep` list matching filenames, and then pipe/send that output to where you need the results.

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 egrep -l pattern > matching_filenames
```

Also note that `grep -E` (or `egrep`) uses extended regular expressions, which means parentheses create a regex group. If you want to search for files containing `(GNU)` (with the parentheses) use `grep -F` or `fgrep` instead, which treats the pattern as a string literal.

Comment: what if I do want to have a list of files that do not match the regex, **also**?

Comment: The `-L` option lists files not matching.

Comment: Last question, the second option lists the (non) matching files in a file, is it possible to build an array with the result? So I do not need to read the contents of the file and afterwards delete it.

Comment: Your comment about `-exec` running once per result is only true if you use `-exec cmd {} \;`. If you use `-exec cmd {} +` then it will pass multiple results to `cmd` at once.

Comment: You can just put the result in an array `()` with command substitution `$()`: `RESULT=($(find . -print0 | xargs -0 fgrep -L pattern))`.