# Bash command to find all Fortran files in a directory

Tags: bash, grep, find, fortran

I am trying to find all the Fortran files in a directory and replace some text in that file.

At first i was thinking of using `find -regex ... -exec` to find all the file extensions for fortran code and make replacements. However, there are a lot of file extensions, is there another way to identify fortran files?

Comment: Why are there lots of extensions for fortran files?

Comment: @Barmar Because there are two source forms and capital F denotes the necessity of preprocessing. And because people think that they should distinguish different versions of standard (nonsense like `.f95`,`.f03`), which is silly. Like if we had `.java1` `.java2` ... `.java7`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very short find command to find all Fortran related files. The most common Fortran files are `*.f`, `*.f90`, and their capital letter counterparts. Additionally, `.f95`, `.f03`, `.f08`, and even `.for` are used. Note that `-iregex` matches the regular expression case insensitive (in contrast to `-regex`).

```
find . -iregex ".*\.F[0-9]*" -o -iregex ".*\.for"
```

To do something with this, you can use `xargs`:

```
find . -iregex ".*\.F[0-9]*" -o -iregex ".*\.for" | xargs head -1
```

Replace `head -1` with whatever you want to do with the files.

---

Another way to work with that is using a loop such as:

```
for file in $(find . -iregex ".*\.F[0-9]*" -o -iregex ".*\.for"); do
  head -1 "$file"
done
```

This gives you a bit more flexibility than the `xargs` approach, and is easier to read.

Comment: Unless output is very simple (no whitespace, no special character) or you explicitly want word-splitting you generally shouldn't use `for ... in $(command)` in bash. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7039579/3076724 for some alternatives (missing `IFS=` in a few places)