# /usr/bin/find: Argument list too long in for loop bash script

Tags: linux, bash, find, quoting, glob

I have such a bash script. I want to `gzip` all *.ppm* files under a directory to another directory. For this reason I have written such a bash script:

```
cd /export/students/sait/12-may
for next_file in  $(find . -type f  ! -name *.ppm )
do
/bin/gzip -f -c $next_file > /export/students/sait/12-may-yedek/$next_file.gz
done
```

When I execute this script, I get such error:

```
/usr/bin/find: Argument list too long
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: If you for some reason do need to loop, see [Bash : iterate over list of files with spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7039579/3076724). i.e. do `find .... -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do echo "$file"; done`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quote this part : `*.ppm` to prevent filename globbing, and also remove the `!` as you want to find files with `.ppm` extension, not the other way around.

```
find . -type f  -name '*.ppm'
```

---

Instead of running a loop you could do it with single `find` command which would provide white space safety:

```
find /export/students/sait/12-may -type f -name '*.ppm' -exec sh -c '/bin/gzip -f -c "$0" > "$0".gz' {} \;
```

Comment: Thank you. But at this time it gets other files which doesn't have .ppm extension.

Comment: @yusuf : You were using `!` to reverse the logic.