# Shell Script Issue with Multiple Filetypes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, openssl

Some of my files are separated into different directories such as */apps*, */games*, */docs* etc....
Within each directory, is a subdirectory called *_CHECKSUM*.  Inside this directory, is a file called *openssl.sh*.

For example:

```
openssl sha1 /path/to/apps/*.iso | sed 's/\/.*.\///' > /path/to/apps/_CHECKSUM/sum.sha1
```

This outputs to a file called *sum.sha1* within the *_CHECKSUM* directory, of which the contents could look like this:

```
SHA1(anApp.iso)= b398c8b175411e6174942d7b4acbc5c90473a852
SHA1(anotherApp.iso)= cc150483feed3d4b607749f31eddccefd0ba5478
SHA1(yetAnotherApp.iso)= d9682a2eca25b70dddf7a906374c27ee35614c7d
```

However, some directories contain multiple filetypes, so the script would have to look like this:

```
openssl sha1 /path/to/games/*.{7z,iso} | sed 's/\/.*.\///' > /path/to/games/_CHECKSUM/sum.sha1
```

producing something like this:

```
SHA1(myFaveGame.7z)= b398c8b175411e6174942d7b4acbc5c90473a852
SHA1(anotherGoodGame.iso)= cc150483feed3d4b607749f31eddccefd0ba5478
```

I don't want to always run these scripts manually, so I created the following script, */path/to/scripts/openssl_recursive.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash
# finds every openssl.sh recursively and executes it.
IFS=$'\n'
for file in $(find /path/to -name "openssl.sh" | sort -n)
do
  echo "executing $file ..."
  sh $file
  echo "done.";
done
```

This seems to work fine for all directories where just one file type exists.  However, for the *openssl.sh* scripts that contain multiple extensions, an empty *sum.sha1* file is created.

Why is it that if I run the *openssl.sh* directly, it will create the correct result in *sum.sha1* for directories with multiple filetypes, yet if I run the *openssl_recursive.sh*, this results in an empty *sum.sha1*?

Comment: maybe because he dnt know the path.Maybe you need to cd to that directory etc

Comment: can you try 1) running it as `/bin/bash $file` and 2) workaround: `openssl sha1 /path/to/games/*.7z /path/to/games/*.iso`

Comment: Why are you calling `sh $file` instead of making it executable and put a `#!/bin/bash` at the top and invoke `$file`

Comment: Pleas post the output of `bash -x ./openssl_recursive.sh`. Also see [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639), [Looping through files with spaces in the names?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9496), [How to list filenames that contain spaces and special characters without using find](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/232058), [Iterate over list of files with spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7039130), etc. All of them tell how to iterate over the files, and how to further process them.

Comment: The output of `bash -x ./openssl_recursive.sh` is as follows:

+ IFS='
'
++ sort -n
++ find /path/to/games -name openssl.sh
+ for file in '$(find /path/to/games -name "openssl.sh" | sort -n)'
+ echo 'executing /path/to/games/_CHECKSUM/openssl.sh ...'
executing /path/to/games/_CHECKSUM/openssl.sh ...
+ sh /path/to/games/_CHECKSUM/openssl.sh
/path/to/games/*.{7z,iso}: No such file or directory
+ echo ' done.'
 done.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - Yes, the `/bin/bash $file` replacement worked.  This recursively created a complete _sum.sha1_ file in each sub-directory, even if the directory had multiple filetypes.  I'm still a newcomer to Linux and shell scripting.  Please can you tell me the difference between using `sh` and `/bin/bash` and why I should not use `sh` in this instance.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash), modern Debian and Ubuntu systems symlink sh to `dash` by default, which is a lighter version and lacks some advanced features.

So this may not be the same shell, and probably doesn't like "rich" wildcard constructs like `*.{7z,iso}`. You must have fallen into that category.

On the other hand, `bash` accepts those wildcards happily.

So a working solution is forcing the use of `/bin/bash` env variable:

```
#!/bin/bash
# finds every openssl.sh recursively and executes it.
IFS=$'\n'
for file in $(find /path/to -name "openssl.sh" | sort -n)
do
  echo "executing $file ..."
  /bin/bash $file
  echo "done.";
done
```

Comment: I am indeed using a Debian system and this was very informative.  I went ahead and used your `/bin/bash` example and this worked, but I will also experiment with `$SHELL` as this seems to be a more robust option.  Thank you!

Comment: When using `$SHELL $file`, as used in the above example, it still results in empty sum.sha1 files.  I reverted back to using `/bin/bash $file`, which works.