# Bash syntax weirdness with files with spaces

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Here's a problem you may be familiar with: I wanted to make an inquiry into my disk usage on my Mac, so I tried in my home directory

```
~/$> for file in `ls`; do du -hs $file; done
```

with output

```
 55M    Applications
107M    Desktop
132G    Documents
5.1G    Downloads
 16G    Library
457M    Music
 53M    Pictures
du: VirtualBox: No such file or directory
du: VMs: No such file or directory
```

which is great except for the last one because it is a directory called "VirtualBox VMs" -- there is a space in the name. I google it (actually, all I had to do was start typing "bash loop..." and it autocompleted to "bash loop over files with spaces" -- thanks Google!) and I get this question, [Iterate over list of files with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039130/iterate-over-list-of-files-with-spaces), as the first result.

If you peruse that thread, you'll find a lot of complicated solutions that use `xargs` or something weird. Of course, I could write my own functions to handle these cases, but I was pretty adamant about having a one line solution. Thus, in my opinion, the hands-down best solution (though not the top-voted or accepted solution) was

```
for file in *; do du -hs "${file}"; done
```

Somewhat perversely, the following don't work:

1. Removing the quotes

   ```
   for file in *; do du -hs ${file}; done  #splits on spaces and throws error
   ```
2. Using `ls`, even with the quotes:

   ```
   for file in `ls`; do du -hs "${file}"; done #splits on spaces and throws error
   ```

My question is, **Can some bash expert explain to me exactly what the difference between all these is, and why the ones that fail fail?**

Comment: [BashPitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) would be a place to start.

Comment: You might also read [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: ...and reading the explanations of why the faulty code is faulty from https://shellcheck.net/ is another useful place to be.

Comment: _thanks guys this is the stuff I needed_

Comment: YO shellcheck is a dope tool in addition to being a great resource

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I came on this question to cite exactly those links ... you beat me to it. Put those as an answer, maybe?

Comment: @OlivierDulac, ...frankly, I don't think this question *should* be answered -- I'm the vote-to-close (as "too broad", being as it's a conglomeration of individual questions, each of which has a duplicate already in our knowledge base). Feel free to add one yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realize that the working case expands to: `du -hs "VirtualBox VMs"`.

1. For this case, the issue is that the command expands to:
   `du -hs VirtualBox VMs`
   This passes two file names to the `du` command.
2. For this case, the issue is that the `for` command sees two separate tokens. So the iteration iterates over each separately.
   `du -hs VirtualBox`
   `du -hs VMs`

Answer (score 0):

This is all explained by the fact that word-splitting happens after process substitution and parameter expansion. So the result of `$(ls)` as well as `${file}` undergoes word-splitting, while the double quotes in `"${file}"` suppress word-splitting.