# Putting files into a file and changing the rights

Tags: linux, bash

I have to make a bash script: *I've a directory and I'm reading all the files that are in the directory  and I have to find the files to which the members of the group have no rights, after all this files I have to put into another file and set the write right (w) to the members of the group (g).*

I figured out how to find the files where members of the group have no rights, but I don't know how to put the files into another file and set the writing right to the members of the group. Can somebody help me?

I write `` echo `find $1 ! -perm /g=rwx` `` just to see if the files are correctly taken.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [  $# -eq 0 ] 
        then echo "Nu exista parametri"
        exit 1
fi

if [ ! -d $1 ]
        then echo "It's not a directory"   #Check if the parameter is a directory
        exit 1
fi

echo `find $1 ! -perm /g=rwx`
```

Answer (score 1):

If by putting the files into another file you mean copying them, you can do that as follows:

```
cp source-file target-file
```

and you can then change the owning group with

```
chgrp your-group target-file
```

and, if still necessary, you can add write permission for that group with

```
chmod g+w target-file
```

For documentation run

```
man cp
man chgrp
man chmod
```

Answer (score 1):

@afdggfh beet me to it, but a complete solution might look like:

```
files=$(find $dir ! -perm /g=rwx)
for file in $files; do
    trg=$trgdir/$(basename $file)
    cp $file $trg;
    chmod g+w $trg;
done;
```

---------------- EDIT -------------

Alternatively, you could add and `-exec` parameter to find.   This parameter allows you to execute a command in place.   In this case, `{}` represents the filename found, and `\;` represents the end of the exec command:

```
find $dir ! -perm /g=rwx -exec cp {} $trgdir \; -exec chmod g+w {} \;
```

This solution works for all filenames (including those with spaces, asterisks and newlines).

Comment: This breaks for file names with spaces in them, and file names undergo expansion.

Comment: Could you tell me what this line `trg=$trgdir/$(basename file)` does?

Comment: this populates `$trg`, to hold the name of the target file.   `$trgdir` is assumed to be the directory you are using for your target files.   `$(basename $file)` is the filename without the directory.  (oops, I forgot the `$` in my answer... updating),

Comment: As @BenjaminW. pointed out, this will not work for filenames with spaces.  If you want to handle these, you can either set `IFS` to be `\n`, or use a while loop as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039130/iterate-over-list-of-files-with-spaces)

Comment: The path expansion is more problematic, in my opinion. If you have a filename containing `*`, it'll expand to all files in the directory.

Comment: I just tried the `find` piped into `while`, and it handles both whitespace and `*`'s, but doesn't handle newlines...   I just looked and found a [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7039579/7673414) online that will handle those as well (though it's getting a bit hard to read...   It would be simpler to do it as an `-exec` on the find at that point.   I'll update my post.

Comment: You can use `find -print0 | while read -d ''` for nul character delimited filenames – but `-exec` works fine and is safe with respect to expansions.